# Include the Java agent with a JVM argument in Catalina.sh

Tags: tomcat, java, newrelic

I am trying to install newrelic agent on my linux server and following https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/installation/install-java-agent and stuck in step 3 of install the java agent - includeJava agent with a JVM argument.

I am new to this not sure how to pass the -javaagent argument on Tomcat, pls see below and could you pls let me know where to place below line in catalina.sh file.

```
Configure your catalina.sh file to use the New Relic agent using the JAVA_OPTS environment variable:
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/full/path/to/newrelic.jar"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `catalina.sh` file itself warns you:

```
# Environment Variable Prerequisites
#
#   Do not set the variables in this script. Instead put them into a script
#   setenv.sh in CATALINA_BASE/bin to keep your customizations separate.
```

You should consider the New Relic instructions are slightly wrong and place the line in `setenv.sh` instead. Create the file if it does not exist.

Comment: Just created a file named "setevn.sh" with `JAVA_OPTS="-javaagent:/usr/newrelic-temp/newrelic/newrelic.jar"`i.e., path for my newrelic.jar file